# Actions don't have "type" - Error In React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in React Native, Trying to learn redux, with functional components, stuck on this error.
"Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?".

Creating a simple. to-do list.

My Redux.js file...

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {uuid} from 'react-native-uuid';

const initialState = {
  todos: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Test ToDo 1',
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Test ToDo 2',
      completed: true,
    },
  ],
};

export const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('type ' + JSON.stringify(action));
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD-TODO':
      return {...state, todos: [...state, action.payload]};
    case 'TOGGLE-TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.map((todo) =>
          todo.id === action.payload
            ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
            : todo,
        ),
      };
    case 'DELETE-TODO':
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const addToDoAction = (todo) => ({
  type: 'ADD-TODO',
  payload: todo,
});

export const toggleToDoAction = (todoId) => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE-TODO',
  payload: todoId,
});

export const deleteToDoAction = (todoId) => ({
  type: 'DELETE-TODO',
  payload: todo,
});
```

Here is the ToDO Input component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {addToDoAction} from '../redux/redux';
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

const ToDoInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Test');
  const addToDo = useDispatch((todo) => addToDoAction(todo));
  const onChangeText = (text) => {
    setText(text);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Add To Do</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
        editable={true}
        value={text}
      />
      <Button
        title={'Add ToDo'}
        onPress={() =>
          addToDo({
            id: uuid.v4(),
            name: text,
            completed: false,
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ToDoInput;
```

When I tap the add button, I am getting error...

"Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?".

This is my app.js file. contents.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './redux/redux';
import ToDoInput from './components/ToDoInput';
import ToDoList from './components/ToDoList';
import AddItem from './components/AddItem';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 100}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 100}}>
          <ToDoInput />
          {/* <ToDoList /> */}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 60,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Couldn't find a way to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead.

```
const ToDoInput = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch(); <-- add this line

  const addToDo = useDispatch((todo) => addToDoAction(todo)); <--- remove this line

  // update the callback passed into onPress as seen below

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={'Add ToDo'}
        onPress={() =>
          dispatch(addToDoAction({
            id: uuid.v4(),
            name: text,
            completed: false,
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @codemax. it worked. Can you please explain it to me why the other approach didn't work. it would be a great help.

Comment: Your approach might work if `useDispatch()` accepts an argument. But it does not. See [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.js#L14).

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much